# Apach Nifi revert flowfile attribute

Tags: apache-nifi

In my Nifi 1.3.0 dataflow the FetchElasticsearchHttp processor changes the filename attribute to its corresponding ID in the database. I was wondering if there was a way of changing it back using some of Nifi's in house processors.

I have thought about simply writing my own script to correct this but there seems to be no way of knowing what file it is so I can't just grab its name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if I understood you correctly, you can use UpdateAttribute to copy the filename attribute to another property. There's no way to stop the processor from writing its properties, but you can surely stash it away yourself. The trick is to copy/rename before invoking the fetch processor.

Comment: For a fix I have two update attributes one at the top to create temp.filename and then after it corrects it and deletes temp.filename in a second update attribute.